# How to conditionally define bold for selected categoryLabels using amcharts library?

Tags: amcharts

**Problem:**

I'm not able to pass bold attribute to desired labels in the category Axis using amcharts library.

**Case:**

I'm able to pass fillColor for each element of my chart using the dataset itself. This is an example of the dataset structure I am using:

```
var ordArray2 = [{"shop_name":"eBay - marsmediagmbh1","price_with_shipping":"369.00","color":"#769CC1","bold":false},{"shop_name":"CHECK24","price_with_shipping":"375.00","color":"#228172","bold":true}];
```

Bar color is, therefore, defined in the graphs class:

```
"graphs": [
                        {
                            "colorField": "color",
                            "fillAlphas": 1,
                            "id": "AmGraph-1",
                            "lineColorField": "color",
                            "title": "graph 1",
                            "type": "column",
                            "valueField": "price_with_shipping",
                            "balloonText" : "[[category]]: <b>[[value]] €</b>"
                        }
                    ]
```

However, this principle doesn't seem to work within the class categoryAxis, as the following code just applies bold to all the labels, and not only to those marked as `true` for the key `bold`in the dataset:

```
 "categoryAxis": {
        "autoRotateAngle": 45,
            "autoRotateCount": 0,
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "titleRotation": null,
            "boldLabels": "bold"
    }
```

I have tried passing the bold key as boolean and as string, and the effect is the same.

**Code & Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/uhxuw6ov/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently is no direct option to set font weight for individual category axis labels.

There are a couple of options for you to consider:

### Option 1: Use different color to distinguish individual labels

For that you can use [`labelColorField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelColorField):

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "autoRotateAngle": 45,
  "autoRotateCount": 0,
  "gridPosition": "start",
  "boldLabels": "bold",
  "labelColorField": "color"
}
```

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/uhxuw6ov/2/

### Option 2: Use CSS to set font weight for individual labels

You can use [`classNameField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#classNameField) to apply special class names to individual category axis labels. Then target them via CSS.

In data:

```
{
  "shop_name": "Alternate.de",
  "price_with_shipping": "405.95",
  "color": "#2c3e50",
  "labelClass": "bold-label"
}
```

In chart config:

```
"addClassNames": true,
"categoryAxis": {
  "autoRotateAngle": 45,
  "autoRotateCount": 0,
  "gridPosition": "start",
  "classNameField": "labelClass"
}
```

Notice, the [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames) is required. Without it no class names are applied to chart elements including the ones that should come via `classNameField`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhxuw6ov/3/

Note that CSS approach will work on modern, SVG-enabled browsers. Legacy IEs that do not support SVG will ignore this setting.

Comment: Perfect! I would have never thought about using classes. I have done a combination of both approaches and the result is beautiful!

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help.